# Value of textbox in modal popup is empty

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-modal, postback

I have a modal popup with two textboxes in my asp.net page. I want to get the textbox values in server side. But its empty in ButtonClick event.

This is my page.

```
<div class="modal inmodal fade in" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width: 830px;">

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Item Account Maintenance

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 13px 27px;">
                <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 14px;  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray; margin-left: -28px; margin-right: -28px; border-color: lightgray;">

                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div role="form">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Item Number</label>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator40" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" CssClass="label label-danger"
                                    ControlToValidate="txtItemNo" ValidationGroup="BT"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemNo"  placeholder="" runat="server" class="form-control btn-rounded modalControl"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Description</label>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator41" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" CssClass="label label-danger"
                                    ControlToValidate="txtDesc" ValidationGroup="BT"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                <input type="text" id="txtDesc" runat="server" class="form-control btn-rounded modalControl" placeholder="" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>

            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
    </div>

</div>
```

This is buttonClick Event

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DOL.ItemAccount obj = new DOL.ItemAccount();
        obj.ItemNumber= txtItemNo.Text ;
        obj.ItemDesc = txtDesc.Value;
        BAL.ItemAccount.InsertItemAccount(obj);
}
```

But txtItemNo.Text shows empty. Can anybody give me a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is btnSave button you have called for???

Comment: Button for Popup :
' _<button type="button" id="btnAccount" class="btn btn-white" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Accounts</button>_ '

Button for Save :
 _<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnSave_Click" ValidationGroup="BT" />_

Comment: try removing validation group from button click

Comment: I removed Validation group.. stil its not working

Comment: Do you have code in pageload to clear textbox? Are you checking if(!IsPostback).. ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46013822/7920473

Comment: @Arun, I am using bootstrap modal pop up and not clearing textbox on page load. I have some code inside (!IspostBack)  to display values on textbox. That is working fine. But when click save button value is lost.

Comment: is `btnSave` firing the `OnClick()` event?

Comment: for me placing the modal inside the `UpdatePanel` will allow the date picker value passed to server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` attribute to the `btnSave`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem erasing all "form" tags. For example: `"<div role="form"> "` or `"<form>"`, the reason is that the asp content is inherited from master page and a page can have only one server-side "Form" tag.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers to multiple questions. If the questions are duplicates, flag them to be closed as such.

Comment: Ok, sorry and thanks. The next time i will flag them.